# How to chain django query filters to conditionally filter by certain criteria

Tags: python, django

I have a Django page that shows a table generated from rows in a database table.  Alongside that table, there are filtering criteria in a form so the user can search by different criteria.  When the user tries to filter by whatever chosen criteria, I will need to optionally fitler my database call in my view.  For example, this is what I tried:

```
user_profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(some_base_criteria=True).exclude(user__id__in=some_ids)

    if request.method == "POST":
        gender = request.POST["gender"]
        if gender != "any":
            user_profiles.filter(gender=gender)
```

This doesn't operate as expected, since it seems to OR those 2 filter criteria together, rather than AND them together.

How do you AND multiple filter criteria together without putting all of the options into one long filter, since the filter may or may not require specific criteria for any given query?

Comment: It's a bad practice - use variable from user (directly from request.POST). You must create form, validate and then, use value from dict  form.cleaned_data

Comment: @mrvol I've seen that in a few spots, but I've found that getting good formatting on a Django form is tough, because you don't actually list out the individually rendered fields in your template.

Comment: OK, now I am calm =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has no effect:

```
user_profiles.filter(gender=gender)
```

you must reassign the result:

```
user_profiles = user_profiles.filter(gender=gender)
```